# Extract value from complex array of map type to string

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below.

```
No    comp_value
1     [[ -> 10]]
2     [[ -> 35]]
```

The schema type of column - value is.

```
comp_value: array (nullable = true)
      element: map(containsNull = true)
              key: string
              value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I would like to convert the comp_value from complex type to string using PySpark. Is there a way to achieve this?

Expected output:

```
No    comp_value
1     10
2     35
```

Comment: Can you please give a script to produce your df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,' [[ -> 10]]'),
     (2, '[[ -> 35]]')],
    ['No', 'v'])


df.show()
```

replace the corner brackets, remove trailing spaces, split by space to get a list and get the elements you want by slicing the list

```
new = df.withColumn('comp_value', split(trim(regexp_replace('v','\[|\]','')),'\s')[1])

new.show()

+---+-----------+----------+
| No|          v|comp_value|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  1| [[ -> 10]]|        10|
|  2| [[ -> 35]]|        35|
+---+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your data looks like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 10),
     (2, 35)],
    ['No', 'v'])
df = df.select('No', F.array(F.create_map(F.lit(''), 'v')).alias('comp_value'))

df.show()
# +---+----------+
# |No |comp_value|
# +---+----------+
# |1  |[{ -> 10}]|
# |2  |[{ -> 35}]|
# +---+----------+
```

You can extract values inside array by referencing to them using index number (in this case `[0]`). And extracting values from maps is done by referencing keys (in this case `['']`).

```py
df2 = df.select('No', F.col('comp_value')[0][''].cast('string').alias('comp_value'))

df2.show()
# +---+----------+
# |No |comp_value|
# +---+----------+
# |  1|        10|
# |  2|        35|
# +---+----------+
```